# Apply VSCode decorator to empty space after text ends

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a decorator that highlights blocks of code by their common indentation level, and I'd like for it to create a single color rectangle that indicates the text is a cohesive block.

For example, take this python code:

```
for n in range(1,100):
  print(f"Processing {n}")
  my_array.append(n)
  print("Done!")
```

If I highlight line 3, I want lines 2, 3, and 4 highlighted to the length of the longest line, which in this case is line 2 with 27 characters.

I have written the following to apply the decorator to each of the lines in this:

```
  function applyMaxLengthDecoratorToLinesInRange(text_range: vscode.Range, max_length: number, indent_level: number) {
    let decorationsArray = [];

    highlightDecoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,64,0.5)"
    });

    for (let line = text_range.start.line; line <= text_range.end.line; line++) {
      let range = new vscode.Range(line, indent_level, line, max_length);

      decorationsArray.push(range);
    }

    activeEditor.setDecorations(highlightDecoration, decorationsArray);
  }
```

I have validated that every line's `Range` object has the same start and end point on their respective line. The problem is that I can't seem to get the decorator to apply beyond the last character of each line. There's the option to use `isWholeLine` in the decorator options, but that extends far beyond and doesn't begin at the indentation level I want.

This produces the following on the python example above:
[current behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSn0A.png)

I'd like for it to produce this: [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CWym.png) (I just added whitespace to lines 3 and 4 to make this happen)

I can't seem to find any options in [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions) around allowing space after the final character to be included when the range specifies it, but clearly vscode has some manner of applying formatting to that area since `isWholeLine` exists.